# Column changes values when inserted into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query which I use to transfer data from one table to another, but when I select values from the second table, it shows the next integers in the specific column, that column has IDENTITY constraint in first table but it doesn't transfer as it.

```
insert into Table2 (id, name, phone)
    select ID, Name, Phone 
    from Table1
```

Table1 values are

```
1 John  123456
2 David 456789
3 Tony  547892
```

but in Table2 it shows

```
4 John  123456
5 David 456789
6 Tony  547892
```

How can I avoid that increment in `ID` column, while Table2 `ID` column doesn't have `IDENTITY` constraint?

Comment: its sql-server not mysql

Comment: You may have IDENTITY on Table 2 as well; check the table structure, set identity off, insert and then set identity on

Comment: IDENTITY is off on table2, I checked and made sure before, and I don't want to set IDENTITY on table2

Comment: when you say `select ID, Name, Phone from Table1` does it return 1,2,3 as you expect to be inserted?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions, but a quick workaround would be the following:

```
insert into Table2 (id, name, phone)
select (ID * 1)
       ,Name
       ,Phone 
from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force SQL to accept an identity and not generate it's own -- BUT be warned there could be duplicate identity issues.

```
set identity_insert table2 on

insert into Table2 (id, name, phone)
select ID, Name, Phone from Table1

set identity_insert table2 off
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms188059.aspx

Another option, depending on your situation, is to issue a `TRUNCATE TABLE table2` to erase EVERY row before insert -- but this also resets the identity to 1.